# Which one is the best for creating android material icons?

Tags: icon, android

I am a new designer. I need to design an icon for my android application. But I need to make it material. So now I am asking to you that which one is best for me to creat a material icon?
And if here anyone suggest about Adobe then my question will be to him that which is best for android - Illustrator or Photoshop CC?
Thanks^-^

Comment: You can make it in either... I think illustrator would be better as you can do more with an SVG file and the fact that it can be scaled to any size. But if it is only to put on the APP store, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes. I thought it. Illustrator is better than CC. Ok thanks however^-^

Comment: I'll second AndrewH here. Illustrator is preferred with logos/icons because it is in a vector format that can be indefinitely scaled. Also wanted to clarify that Illustrator can CC be as well. CC stands for Creative Cloud and refers more to the version of the product rather than the product itself. In other words, if you have a Creative Cloud subscription you will be running  both Illustrator CC and Photoshop CC.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is review the Google Material Design icon style guide: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html

As for software either Illustrator or Photoshop will be able to export files for use in your application. Personally I would use Illustrator as I prefer the workflow, and you can still use some of the effects from Photoshop (These can be found in Effects - Photoshop Effects.)